# Camunda: Receive multiple, different messages at once

Tags: spring, synchronization, message, bpmn, camunda

I am currently developing a kinda complex workflow with camunda. The goal of this workflow is to orchestrate the execution of different external business processes. Which includes start, overwatch and synchronize these workflows. Everything besides the synchronization works as expected.

### Example:

My example has one main workflow which starts multiple sub workflows. The main workflow has to be aware when all sub workflows are finished. Every sub workflow is triggered by a message and sends a message back to the main workflow at the end of execution. Therefore, all sub workflows should be synchronized in the main workflow.

[image: workflow example]
*Xml can be accessed on this site: https://pastebin.com/2aj4z0zU*

Unfortunately, this leads to numerous message correlation exceptions at the choke point in the main workflow (1st lane, after the first parallel gateway). I am using the following code to correlate the messages:

```
 this.runtimeService.createMessageCorrelation(messageName)
            .processInstanceId(processInstanceId)
            .setVariables(payload)
            .correlate();
```

The whole workflow is executable and runs without errors, but only if one example_workflow at a time is executed. Starting multiple example_workflows quickly one after another results in this type of exception randomly for every message type:

```
ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: Cannot correlate message 'PROCESS_B_FINISHED': No process definition or execution matches the parameters org.camunda.bpm.engine.MismatchingMessageCorrelationException: Cannot correlate message 'PROCESS_B_FINISHED': No process definition or execution matches the parameters
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.CorrelateMessageCmd.execute(CorrelateMessageCmd.java:88) ~[camunda-engine-7.14.0.jar!/:7.14.0]
```

Currently, the correlation exceptions occur if a postgresql database is used. The same workflow runs much better, but not perfect, when we use a h2 file-based database. All receive tasks are not configured asynchronously, only send tasks are (async before + exclusive).

### Questions:

Is this already the best practice to synchronize multiple messages in one workflow?

What could be the reason for the correlation exceptions while using a postgresql database?

Used software:

- spring boot application [Version:2.3.4]
- camunda [Version:7.14.0]
- h2 [Version:1.4.200]
- postgresql [Version:42.2.22]

Comment: Are you using 3 different message names? How is your async before/after configured? (Easier to check if you share the process model xml here). On a different note: This would better be modeled as a collaboration diagram with 3 separate pools, so you can also model the message flows and give the processes separate names.

Comment: I've updated the post. The xml is now accessible on pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the process model seems to contain sequences where it can run into a deadlock (What if blue is followed directly by green? Or yellow?) or where you have race conditions. If the process has not reached a state where it is in a receiving state for the message, then the message delivery will fail (as indicated in the error message you shared)

(The reason you are observing the CorellationException more frequently on postgresql if the race condition. With this external database some operations take slightly more time, increasing the chance of the race condition occurring).

- The process engine needs to be able to match a message to a unique receiver. If there are multiple potential receivers for the same message name, and no other correlation criteria creating a unique match is provided, then the delivery will also fail. You either need to use unique message names per instance or better use a businessKey or a process data which is unique per instance as additional correlation criteria. This is why it does not work when you run multiple process instances.

Comment: According to your first statement, deadlocks due to miss modeled messages are unlikely. Messages green, red and yellow are only send if the process has reached a certain state (end of lane two).
Your second statement is correct. Unfortunately, the workflow can be successfully executed with a small amount of instances if messages are NOT correlated uniquely. These correlation exceptions occur more frequently with a higher amount of process instances. I guess it is "working" because of the sequential multi instance for the receive tasks.

Comment: A NOT unique correlation will only work if either a) you are using a special API method (correlateAll) or b) if at that particular moment in time / state of the multiple parallel instance, there is only one unique receiver. It sometimes works, when only one instance is in a receiving state for that particular message, but fails if you happen to have two instance in that state. Make the correlation unique by using a unique businessKey and the issue will be solved.

Comment: You are right, despite the fact that a unique business key will not solve the problem. The business key is the same for all messages in one process instance. Therefore, every message has to be correlated with an own unique key on execution level, since there are multiple messages of one type concurrently per process instance. This is shown in the bpmn model above by the parallel execution marker on both receive tasks, red and yellow.

Comment: The bpmn above is not rightfully configured. All multi instance receive tasks (yellow and red, first lane) should be modelled as parallel multi instance tasks instead of sequential.

Answer (score 0):

Modelling a workflow with this parallel message bottleneck leads to a race condition, as mentioned by @rob2universe's post.

To solve this problem, I had firstly to correlate the messages directly. I did this by adding a unique identifier to every message, which was not a big deal due to the fact that an item ID was defined within the payload of every message. Secondly, I had to remove all asynchronous and exclusive markers for every receive task and connected gateways. And thirdly, I had to reset the job executor properties to default values. Limiting the pool size and jobs per acquisition did not benefit the workflow execution.

After all these changes, my workflow now runs as expected with no errors. Unfortunately, due to the described bottleneck optimistic logging exceptions are common, but the workflow engine handles these exceptions without further errors.

Comment: I would encourage you to review the design an consider working with multi-instance call activities instead. Messages are meant for 1:1 communication between different pools (an usually visualized in collaboration diagrams). You seem to be simply using it as a means for parallel processing. The engine / BPMN2 can do this without messages.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning it, but I cannot see how a call activity is suitable in my case. Unfortunately, I did not model everything, including the external systems in my example bpmn. All start messages in my bpmn are invoked by an external system. Using a call activity is not possible for these. Furthermore, call activities cannot be associated to a single execution only to a process definition. The use case for call activities, as mentioned in the official camunda doc, is to invoke subprocesses. All lanes in my bpmn are independent, connected processes, not subprocess within a main process.